# Laravel display "FPDF error: No page has been added yet"

Tags: laravel, fpdf

I am using the fpdf library for my laravel project.  I create a class for the header and footer function.  Then call thess functions on my pdf controller.  I encounter this error "FPDF error: No page has been added yet" and I have no idea where this error came from.  Can you teach me on how to fix this bug/error. Thanks in advance.

Codes from my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Codedge\Fpdf\Fpdf\Fpdf;
use App\Personnel;
use App\Classes\PDFClass;

class PFTReportController extends Controller
{
    public function postPFTReport(Request $request)
    {
        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');
    $pdf->Ln(4);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);

    // Call the header for this report
    $pdfClass = new PDFClass();
    $header = $pdfClass->Header();

    $pdf->Cell(0, 4, 'Sample Report', 0, 1, 'C');
    $pdf->Ln(2);
        
        $pdf->Output();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Code of the class

```
namespace App\Classes;

use Codedge\Fpdf\Fpdf\Fpdf;

class PDFClass extends Fpdf
{
    protected $B = 0;
    protected $I = 0;
    protected $U = 0;
    protected $HREF = '';

    // Page header
    function Header()
    {
        $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 11);
        $this->Cell(0, 2, 'Line 1', 0, 1, 'C');
        $this->Cell(0, 8, 'Line 2', 0, 1, 'C');
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
        $this->Cell(0, 1, 'Line 3', 0, 1, 'C');
        $this->Cell(0, 8, 'Line 4', 0, 1, 'C');
        $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
        $this->Cell(0, 1, 'Line 5', 0, 1, 'C');
        $this->Ln(8);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You create 2 class instances. The first is `FPDF` where you add a page:

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');
$pdf->Ln(4);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
```

...then you create a new one and simply call your `Header()` method manually:

```
$pdfClass = new PDFClass();
$header = $pdfClass->Header();
```

This doesn't make sense and at this point the error is thrown, because you call several methods in `Header()` which should output content to a page but you didn't added one before.

You should only use `PDFClass` and you also should not call the `Header()` method manually because it is [called internally automatically](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/header.htm).

```
public function postPFTReport(Request $request)
{
    $pdf = new PDFClass();
    $pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4'); // NOW THE HEADER() METHOD IS INVOKED AUTOMATICALLY IN THIS CALL
    $pdf->Ln(4);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);

    $pdf->Cell(0, 4, 'Sample Report', 0, 1, 'C');
    $pdf->Ln(2);
    
    $pdf->Output();
    exit;
}
```